# functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

i got confused about seeing the error, can you please help me to sort this issue.

My python code :-

```
# Get image ready for feeding into model
#small_img = imresize(image, (80, 160, 3))
small_img  = resize(image, (80,160), order=3)

small_img = np.array(small_img)
small_img = small_img[None,:,:,:]

# Make prediction with neural network (un-normalize value by multiplying by 255)
prediction = model.predict(small_img)[0] * 255

# Add lane prediction to list for averaging
lanes.recent_fit.append(prediction)
# Only using last five for average
if len(lanes.recent_fit) > 5:
    lanes.recent_fit = lanes.recent_fit[1:]

# Calculate average detection
lanes.avg_fit = np.mean(np.array([i for i in lanes.recent_fit]), axis = 0)

# Generate fake R & B color dimensions, stack with G
blanks = np.zeros_like(lanes.avg_fit).astype(np.uint8)
lane_drawn = np.dstack((blanks, lanes.avg_fit, blanks))

# Re-size to match the original image
#lane_image = imresize(lane_drawn, (720, 1280, 3))
lane_image = resize(lane_drawn, (720,1280), order=3)

# Merge the lane drawing onto the original image
result = cv2.addWeighted(image, 1, lane_image, 1, 0)

return result
```

when i run this code im getting the error like below.

> result = cv2.addWeighted(image, 1, lane_image, 1, 0)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:674: error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'

Can anyone guide me where im doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the element type of `image`?  What is the element type of `lane_image`?  If they are different, you might need to add a `dst` and `dtype` arguments.

Comment: I guess `lane_image` is of data type `float`, because `lanes.avg_fit` is of type `float` as you are applying mean `np.mean`.

Comment: Try this: `result = cv2.addWeighted(image, 1, lane_image.astype(np.uint8), 1, 0)`